# How can I prevent users from downloading MP3s directly

Tags: php, http, drm

I'm building a web-radio like service, in which the user authenticates to the services, gets a cookie and a Flash-based app plays mp3s from the server. The server only delivers if the client is allowed for that particular mp3.

If a user opens a HTTP logger (like FireBug), he can see the files being downloaded by flash. If he opens the mp3 URL directly via the address bar, he can easily download the MP3, although the URLs are not guessable by the user.

I'm looking for a safe system to prevent the user from downloading the MP3 directly to his system. I have examined last.fm, as they use a similar setup, and somehow they prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, you're not going to be able to stop someone who's determined. However, you can at least make it difficult.

There are several options involving referrer checks, authentication, and fun stuff like that. But probably the most successful anti-downloading check I've seen was one that works like this:

The user indicates that he wants to stream a file; the app makes an authenticated, encrypted request indicating his desired action. The result is a one-use-only and time-limited URL that is recognized by whatever application or CDN is hosting the file. After the URL is used once (i.e. by the flash app) it then expires and can never be used again. If the streaming does not start within a given amount of time (several seconds), the URL likewise expires. Obviously the URL given does not directly correspond to the file name, but is instead authenticated, decoded, and translated server-side.

It's still not impossible to work around, but it's fairly difficult.

Comment: That may be a good way, but I'm unsure on how exactly I can let the URLs expire after the first request was started. Any ideas?

Comment: @nanoman, URL should be something like `getstream.php?id=123`, where `id` identifies data from DB and `getstream.php` validates that `id` and, if it is correct, passes file data to client and removes according entry from DB.

Answer (score 1):

You might use RTMP instead of HTTP to deliver audio data. RTMP is meant to be used for *streaming* audio, video and misc data. It streams just *data* rather than a *file*. It's not 100% safe, because if something gets to client (browser, flash player, whatever), user **can** save it, but it's still better than giving a file via HTTP.

You will need a server that supports RTMP though, e.g., Flash Media Server (FMS), Wowza or Red5.

Comment: RTMP has too many disadvantages compared to simple HTTP progressive downloads. The current setup can handle almost 200 stations on one root server, because it doesn't have to provide steady streams.

Comment: @nanoman, you asked for possible solutions - I gave one of them. I wouldn't be surprised if last.fm used it too, though, as I'm not registered there, I cannot check.

Comment: The use of HTTP instead of streaming was a very conscious decision - the product is already up and running. last.fm uses the exact same technology (pandora too) - I don't think you need to register to listen. They seem to have a smart system in place to prevent the direct downloads.

Comment: @nanoman, why the down-vote? Only because you don't like RTMP for some reason, although it actually **would** prevent direct downloads (which is the problem that was described in your question)? As for last.fm, when I click "[Radio](http://www.last.fm/listen)", they redirect me to registering page - that's why I thought that registration is required. If they use HTTP, as you say, then tylerl's solution seems good to me. I've also commented that answer how to achieve "expiring URL" effect.